# How to pass $filter parameters from SAPUI5 application

Tags: request, frontend, sapui5

I'm trying to make request link from input field to backend. My entity set is called ActionsSet, property of entity set is Applctn. I want to pass parameter from input field with Filter operator EQ. I can't figure out the proper way. Here is my code snippet.

```
onPress: function() {
 var oParameter = this.getView().byId("inp").getValue();
 if (oParameter == '') {
    var msg = 'Fill it!';
    MessageToast.show(msg);}
 else{
     var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("<SERVERURL>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZACTIONS_SRV/ActionsSet?$filter = Applctn eq '" + oParameter + "'");    
     }
```

Allright so I made it more simple. But I have this error 400 Bad request as

/ZACTIONS_SRV/ActionsSet/$metadata?$filter%20=%20Applctn%20eq%20%27kjh%27

Maybe problem is that request is in this format
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeDgp.png)

And I guess I need that is this format to pass filter so backend, because this filter works in another app [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsGLW.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my filter is not working in v2.ODataModel "read"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024087/why-my-filter-is-not-working-in-v2-odatamodel-read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serviceUrl will be :

```
serviceUrl: "http://consap2.consit.local:8060/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZACTIONS_SRV/ActionsSet?$filter = Applctn eq '" + oParameter + "'"
```

`oParameter` should be specified in single quotes as `serviceUrl` is enclosed within `" "`

Comment: Thank you for reply, this should be right way but still getting error.  /$metadata?$filter%20=%20Applctn%20eq. I dont know why but I always get also $metadata to url. This could be problem, dont know how to delete from request URL.

Comment: Welcome, can you paste the error, will see if I can help you further

Comment: I edited my original snippet and added screenshots to better subscribe my problem. Thank you @Dopedev for your help.

Comment: Yes, `$metadata` is causing the problem in a request.Only the first model instance triggers a $metadata request. As you are passing `$filter` query option during instantiation, it is considering it as URL parameters that are used for $metadata requests - [Reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.4/docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html). I would suggest you, create model instance then use [read](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read) method's filter option for filtering.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dopedev I found solution and posted code. Thank you for your help and links, were very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I found solution, here is the right way how to post query to OData service:

```
onPress: function() {
 var oParameter = this.getView().byId("inp").getValue();
 if (oParameter == '') {
    var msg = 'Fill it!';
    MessageToast.show(msg);}
 else{
     var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("<SERVERURL>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZACTIONS_SRV/");
     var Filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter('Applctn', 'EQ', oParameter);
     oModel.read("/ActionsSet", {  
          filters: [Filter]  
        });  
    }
```

Comment: Please accept this answer to help readers to find a better solution. The current accepted answer is invalid as `serviceUrl` awaits a service's root URL and **not** a URL to the entity feed.