# Why my filter is not working in v2.ODataModel "read"?

Tags: sapui5

I am using the OData model to read data. But it doesn't work. Check the code below:

```js
getGuid: function(pernr) {
  var self = this;
  var url = "/PersonalDetailSet?$filter=Pernr eq '00000001'";
  self.setBusy(true);
  this.oModel.read(url, {
    success: function(res) {
      // ...
    },
    error: function() {
      // ...
    }
  });
}
```

I don't know why the filter in `url` is not working now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Check if your OData service supports the `$filter` query in the first place.
2. Use the `read` method correctly:

   ```js
   myV2ODataModel.read("/PersonalDetailSet"/* No $filter queries here! */, {
     filters: [ // <-- Should be an array, not a Filter instance!
       new Filter({ // required from "sap/ui/model/Filter"
         path: "myField",
         operator: FilterOperator.EQ, // required from "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator"
         value1: "..."
       })
     ],
     // ...
   });
   ```

- [API reference: `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#read`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read)
- [API reference: `sap.ui.model.Filter`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter)

Answer (score 0):

First you check whether you are getting model in the scope or not. As i can see **this.oModel** which is not proper way of getting model. Better use **this.getModel()** or **this.getView().getModel()** and then check the call. Passing filter is not the right way but still it should work.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to apply additional URL Parameters in the read function you have to do this via the "urlParameters" parameter:

```
getGuid: function(pernr){
    var self = this;
    var url = "/PersonalDetailSet";
    self.setBusy(true);
    this.oModel.read(url, {
        urlParameters: {
            "$filter" : "Pernr eq '00000001'"
        },
        success: function(res){
            self.setBusy(false);
            self.guid = res.results[0].Guid;
        },
        error: function() {
            self.setBusy(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you mean, I should not add the filter in the url?

Comment: Did you try out my suggestion? All the additional URL parameters have to be specified in the "urlParameters" parameter